# ECSCredentials in browser

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a piece of code running in ECS container that starts a browser. The browser needs to get aws credentials to initialize aws clients to call other aws services in the same account.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECSCredentials.html) doc says `This feature is not supported in the browser environment of the SDK` which means we can't do `new AWS.ECSCredentials()` when code is running in the browser.

Is there a workaround to get credentials when code is running in browser?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [1], you need to supply the credential to the SDK in a Web Browser with one of the following methods:

1. Using Amazon Cognito Identity to authenticate users and supply credentials
2. Using web federated identity
3. Hard coded in the script

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html